# Entity Framework eager loading navigation property causes error when using user-defined type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-5

Some background

I'm wanting to bind a list of objects (my model-view) to a grid. The model-view contains fields for both an specific entity and fields from a joined entity.

I was getting an error when I would try to bind due to the dbContext being out of scope. I realized I needed to use the .Include() method in order to eager load my navigation property. However, I suspect that since I'm using Linq to Entities, that I'm now generating another error:

"Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

My code is shown below, any ideas of what I need to do here?

Thanks in advance!

```
    public static List<PlanViewModel> GetPlans()
    {
        using (var context = new RepEntities())
        {

            var query = (from p in context.Plans
                join r in context.RealEstateDetails on p.ReId equals r.ReId
                select new PlanViewModel
                {
                    PlanName = p.PlanName,
                    TargetCompletionDate = p.TargetCompletionDate,
                    ActualCompletionDate = p.ActualCompletionDate,
                    Provision = p.Provision,
                    StatusTypeId = p.StatusTypeId,
                    StatusCommon = p.StatusCommon,
                    Building = r.BuildingName,
                    City = r.City,
                    Country = r.Country
                }).Include("StatusCommon");

            return query.ToList(); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, just put `Include("StatusCommon")` right after `context.Plans`. Because you need to include StatusCommon before the iteration, this way you can set StatusCommon value for every iteration.

```
public static List<PlanViewModel> GetPlans()
        {
            using (var context = new RepEntities())
            {
                var query = (from p in context.Plans.Include("StatusCommon")
                    join r in context.RealEstateDetails on p.ReId equals r.ReId
                    select new PlanViewModel
                    {
                        PlanName = p.PlanName,
                        TargetCompletionDate = p.TargetCompletionDate,
                        ActualCompletionDate = p.ActualCompletionDate,
                        Provision = p.Provision,
                        StatusTypeId = p.StatusTypeId,
                        StatusCommon = p.StatusCommon,
                        Building = r.BuildingName,
                        City = r.City,
                        Country = r.Country
                    }).toList();
                return query;
            }
        }
```